# Using "Zoom" in jqPlot to set datepicker (jquery)

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jqplot

I'm using a normal line chart based on jqPlot. You can zoom in and out (using doubleclick). Additionally I have a datepicker based on a jquery plugin.

Is it possible to set both datepicker-fields (from & to) when people zoom in on the line chart?

Bye

Answer (score 0):

You can bind jqplot's zoom event and get min and max values of zoomed data, and then update your datepicker according to these values :

```
$("#chart1").bind('jqplotZoom, function(){
  var from = new Date(plot.axes.xaxis.min);
  var to   = new Date(plot.axes.xaxis.max);
  //Update your datepicker here.
});
```